# Problems with reading and searching thru txt file with PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a small script which checks if a users has his username in file called whitelist.txt or not. If the username is not found its added. This is the script:

```
$fh = @fopen("whitelist.txt", 'a+');
$stringData = $_POST[usr]. "\n";
if ($fh)
    {
        while (!feof($fh))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($fh);
            if (strpos($buffer, $stringData) == TRUE)
                echo "This username is already whitelisted.";
            elseif (strpos($buffer, $stringData) == FALSE) {
                    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
                    echo "Username ". $stringData. " is now whitelisted.";
                    }
        }
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

What I get now if I enter a new username first time, all is ok. The second time I enter a new username it gets dubbled. Problems go on: if I enter an existing username it gets added twice and the message "This username is already whitelisted." is not shown. Every username is in a new row.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: screams out for the use of a database.

Comment: its a file used by another software so I'm stuck with it.

Comment: in that case you should use === not ==, see the manual page for why

Comment: When you describe the behaviour of this, are you starting with an empty file?

Comment: It dosent matter. Problems happen both times.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if `$fh` is `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT TO ADD**: The accepted answer is great. As a counterpoint, I've modified your code below in the event that you want to continue to read line by line instead of all it once - the file is unlikely to get so big that doing it in one chunk is ever a problem, but making that kind of assumption always makes me very slightly nervous.

---

I see a couple of issues, here:

Even when you find the username in the file, you carry on through the rest of the file, getting false negatives. Try:

```
if (strpos($buffer, $stringData) == TRUE) {
    echo "This username is already whitelisted.";
    break;
}
```

Your `else if` will trigger whenever the script finds a line that doesn't match the submitted username, rather than when it gets to the end of the file. You'll need to move that check outside of the loop so that the new username is only added once. Altogether, now:

```
$fh = @fopen("whitelist.txt", 'a+');
$stringData = $_POST[usr]. "\n";
if ($fh)
    {
        $found = false;
        while (!feof($fh))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($fh);
            if (strpos($buffer, $stringData) == TRUE) {
                echo "This username is already whitelisted.";
                $found = true;
                break;
        }
        if (!$found) {
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            echo "Username ". $stringData. " is now whitelisted.";
        }
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

Comment: This file dose have a tendency to get pretty big :S So Ill use your code :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
$file = 'whitelist.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
if (strpos($contents, $stringData) === FALSE)
{
    $contents .= "\r\n" . $stringData;
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    echo 'Added ' . $stringData . ' to whitelist.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Already whitelisted.';
}
```

And yes, note that it is three equal signs. The problem you probably encountered was that == FALSE was matching the case where the $stringData was the first result (and thus 0, and we all know FALSE == 0) :)

Comment: Would this not result in a false positive if there is a partial match (e.g., "bar\n" would match if the file contained "foobar\n")?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, I think you're right. andreicek you'd probably want to do a preg_match and match the entire line. Something like preg_match('/^'.$stringData.'$/', $contents)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the \n from the string data variable. This is not going to help. 
Also check the result from strpos against true or false with `===`:

```
strpos() === TRUE
```

As 0 and false are the same thing with `==`.

Comment: Without the \n everthing is written in the same row. The other part I don't quite understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too much into the reasons behind the way this code is written, I'd say that @marramgrass has solved the initial problem. However, I'd suggest reading the file into an array using `file()`. Then you can just do a simple check like this:

```
if(strtolower($_POST[usr]) == $Array[index])
{
    echo 'Username is already whitelisted';
}
```

That way the logic is dead simple and you're not dealing with strpos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like you are already opening the file for writing without finding out whether a match occurs or not

```
$username = "thegreatone";
$lines = file("yourfile.txt");
foreach($line as $no => $line) {
    if(strstr($line,$username)) {
       //Now start the hand
       $fp = fopen('whitelist.txt', 'a+');
       fwrite($fp, '\r\n'.$username);
       fclose($fp);

       //Since the search was true... no need to continue the loop
       break;    
    } 
}
```